# Identity MVC Change Password and then login

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm working on an API in which I have implemented Login and ResetPassword functionality. Login works fine and resetPassword also works fine. But when I reset my password and try to login using the new password, login is failing. Upon reset i can see the hash and password fields getting updated but login fails. I'm using the following code for reset.

```
if (user.VerificationCode == model.VerificationCode)
   {
      //var newPasswordHash = UserManager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword(model.NewPassword);
      //var token = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);
      //user.PasswordHash = newPasswordHash;
                        user.Password = model.NewPassword;
      //IdentityResult result = await UserManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user.Id, token, newPasswordHash);
      //IdentityResult result = await UserManager.ChangePasswordAsync(user.Id, user.Password, model.NewPassword);
      var result = await UserManager.UpdateAsync(user);

      if (!result.Succeeded)
      {
          response.Message = AppConstants.Error;
          response.IsSuccess = false;
      }
      else
      {
          response.Message = AppConstants.OperationSuccessful;
          response.IsSuccess = true;
      }

}
```

And for login the already given code using SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync.
Any ideas what is being done wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `UpdateAsync` method, you should hash password first:
This method worked for me:

```
     public async Task<IHttpActionResult> changePassword(UsercredentialsModel usermodel)
{
  ApplicationUser user = await AppUserManager.FindByIdAsync(usermodel.Id);
  if (user == null)
  {
    return NotFound();
  }
  user.PasswordHash = AppUserManager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword(usermodel.Password);
  var result = await AppUserManager.UpdateAsync(user);
  if (!result.Succeeded)
  {
    //throw exception......
  }
  return Ok();
}
```

You can aslo use `RemovePasswordAsync` and `AddPasswordAsync` together to change password:

```
await UserManager.RemovePasswordAsync(userId.Id);

var result = UserManager.AddPasswordAsync(NewPassword);
```